# Windows update from 8.1 to 10 - No metro apps or start menu available cant rollback

Tags: windows-10

I have updated a PC in the test lab from 8.1 to 10 via windows update. No errors or issues reported when updating. It did take along(ish) time to create the user profile.

The existing user has no access to the start menu and neither can I run or get to any metro apps. I have run src /scannow but to no avail.

I cannot rollback to 8.1 because the option to rollback is only on the metro version of settings which I cant get to!

If I create a new user they have the metro apps and start menu but then I cant rollback because it tells me there is a new user!?!

Does anyone have a solution to rolling back this PC to 8.1 without reinstalling when metro has failed..?

Thanks

Comment: have you disabled UAC and run with full admin rights? The new Start is a Store App which requires UAC.

Comment: Does it work now?

Comment: I finally got Metro apps to work by disabling all startup programs and restarting. Working through them to discover which was the culprit. I cannot rollback as I made changes to the user list...though I have removed the extra account and made and disabled the built in administrator account it still says there are changes so I cant rollback =(